# SQL Server - Get all records with invalid date format

Tags: sql-server

In existing database there a field `CreatedOn varchar(10)` which contains some invalid dates like 99/99/9999 and many more.

I want to change all the invalid dates to 1/1/1990, so I can convert this column to datetime by using

```
ALTER TABLE xyzAlter Column CreatedOn DateTime
```

but it is giving error:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime 
   data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Is there any way to get all the records which are not in correct date time format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from yourTable WHERE ISDATE(yourColumn)!=1
```

see: [ISDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx), it returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value, otherwise it returns a 0.

**EDIT** to update then alter your column try this:

```
--table name: xyz
--column name: CreatedOn varchar(10) to datetime

UPDATE xyz
    SET CreatedOn ='1990/01/01'
    WHERE ISDATE(CreatedOn)!=1
GO
ALTER TABLE xyz Alter Column CreatedOn DateTime
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ISDATE ( expression )`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).